# WinAPI - Get all Control-Handles of a Window-Handle

Tags: c#, winapi, ui-automation

i've tried to work a little bit with UI-Automation,
at the moment i try to get all Handles of a process but i've a problem to get all child control Handles.
Anyone know how to get these handles to get the control-rectangle for example?

Comment: Uhm... you don't need window handles for [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). It's the whole idea behind the concept, that it doesn't rely on a certain implementation of the visuals. Most browsers don't have native windows to implement their controls. Neither do Qt applications, or WPF and Modern UI applications. In short: You don't need (and often don't have) window handles when using UI Automation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find all elements relative to given element based on some condition. Then you can get properties from those elements.

For example:

```
var notepad = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
if (notepad != null)
{
    var root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(notepad.MainWindowHandle);
    var elements = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, Condition.TrueCondition)
                        .Cast<AutomationElement>();
    //example:
    //elements.Select(x=>x.Current.Name)
    //elements.Select(x => x.Current.ControlType);
    //elements.Select(x => x.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
    //elements.Select(x => x.Current.BoundingRectangle);
}
```